# Has anyone implemented column selection/highlight with the MUI Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking to implement "column selection" / "highlighting" with the [MUI DataGrid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/). When you click on a column I want to highlight the whole column. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wzrysy?file=demo.tsx